# Deploy Lambda function in 2 Stages of Gateway via serverless

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework

I tried to **deploy a lambda function** via serverless framework in **2 stages** with different environment variables. 
I wanted to have one lambda for production and one for development. The **only difference** is the **environment variable** of the database that should be used.

I used the serverless deploy -s dev and serverless deploy -s prod function to deploy it. The needed roles for example have the suffix -dev or -prod. So there is no problem.

But I'm **not able to use the same API Gateway resource** (e.g. `/foo`) for the GET method. I expected that i would have something like that: `example.com/dev/foo` and `example.com/prod/foo` but unfortunately the following error occurs:

> ApiGateway Method method already exists for this resource

Am i missing something here? Is the method GET method for the resource `/foo` independent of the stage?

Comment: When I do a `-s dev` and `-s prod` each stage gets a separate root address `/dev` and `/prod`. If the APIG existed from before, the Serverless CloudFormation stack cannot create it's own. You may need to delete the APIG that was created previously and allow the Serverless CloudFormation to recreate it.

Answer (score 0):

**This is by design.**
Currently Serverless Framework produce a whole new stack for each stages you deploy to. This design does not allow it to take advantage of API Gateway's stages feature.

There is a pull request referencing your issue [here](https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/2445).
According to this, you might find an alternative with the [serverless-aws-alias plugin](https://github.com/HyperBrain/serverless-aws-alias).